# How to make a metal emboss?

Tags: effects

How to make a metal emboss a reference image attach. Is there any addon to make that effect[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no addon that I know of that can do what you want automatically, you will likely have to do it by hand, one way or another. There are a few workarounds that can fake it, though.

It's an **approximation**, but you could use a Bezier Curve, with a square section used as bevel object and manually draw your text shapes.

Have in mind that it wont correctly make the beveled ends like in your reference image. You would have to do those manually by hand in the end by converting the curve to mesh first.

[image]

**EDIT**

Create a new plane mesh object, rotate it $45º$ in Z Axis, apply the rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation* then convert it to mesh with <kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Curve from Mesh*.

Now add a new Bezier Curve object that will make up your text. Under the *Properties Editor > Object Data > Bevel Object* pick the plane created in the previous steps.

Adjust the square plane size as needed.

That should get your bevel started, now just manually edit your curve object so it is shaped like the letters of the text you want.

As mentioned earlier this method wont cap the ends correctly with a bevel like in your image. You will have to manually create those yourself if you want, by converting (a copy) to a mesh first. Keep an original copy around as curve just to be safe.

Comment: Okay, this is a brilliant approach :).

Comment: @JachymMichal you can combine it with [Font Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52971/19307) for a more maintainable solution

Comment: Will try, thanks :)