# Trapeze profile for 3D letters, lines

Tags: 3d-printing, bevel

Can somebody please help me? I should make fondant/marzipan stamp. I can make the 3D object - letters, lines (extrude from the svg) but I do not know how to set that profile where the top is narrower than the base (like a kind of  trapeze as you can see on the picture) So I can easier remove the stamp from the material... Somebody said that would be the bevel but I could not make it :-(
[image]
Thank you for your help in advance
Zsolt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a metal emboss?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a bevel on text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text)

Answer (score 1):

I made a textobject in Blender, but with svg curves this could also work. The bevel is the outer form of your geometry. Than I added a curvecircle and defined it right as bavel object (yellow) and got the result at the right sight. You should set the vektor handles (v in curve edit mode) of the circle to free to get sharp angles. Also you should use only one core as a contour. (Red in the exmaple)

[image]