# Round beveled text

Tags: text-object, bevel

Is there easy way of having a rounded bevel on text… ie like so…

[image]

It was painful to model this on the text and when I added a bevel I got all sorts of bad geometry and had to rebuild it etc, like so…

[image]

so just wondering if there was an easy way I was missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah no worries,

I've converted to a mesh like so...

https://i.imgur.com/W8yf6aX.jpg

 then added a middle bunch of edges...

https://i.imgur.com/p7fEsk4.jpg

raised them up..

https://i.imgur.com/2dHp5gU.jpg

and beveled but it gets all messed up...

https://i.imgur.com/6o83DBs.jpg

so just wondering if theres an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please don't use the comments to add images like that. Edit your original post to update your progress and make the images visible as part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

[image: final]

I would personally go with [Skin modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html). It can be a bit tricky sometimes but after you will "feel" it, you'll have fun.

### Mesh.

[image: mesh]

Simple extrusion from one vertex. No faces.

### Modifiers.

[image: mods]

First **Subdivision** for smoothing base mesh.

**Skin** for creating mesh.

Second **Subdivision** to smooth Skin results.

Most important thing here is that you will need to manually set **Vertex Data radius** by selecting vertex and scaling it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.