# How to Offset Geometry of a Text Converted to Mesh

Tags: edit-mode, geometry

I have a text object that has been converted to mesh. Recreating it as text is not ideal. I need to do the geometry offset of the characters (on $X$ and $Z$ axes).

Scaling wouldn't work as it doesn't scale the stroke but the shape overall. For example: I have an 'O' character ($20$m x $30$m) and I need the outer oval to get smaller and the inner oval to get bigger both by $0.2$ .

It is less straight-forward with characters like 'C' or '3'.

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you would [edit] your question and add illustrative images of your problem so that users can see what you are working with.

Comment: Timaroberts - will do next time. This time moonboots did it for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, first simplify your letters topology with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.

For some letters a simple inset (<kbd>i</kbd>) will work (and then invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and delete the outer edges):

[image]

For some other letters it won't work and you'll have to extrude them, *Shrink/Fatten* with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, and delete the extrusion:

[image]

Comment: moonboots - thank you ever so much! That works like charm. I can't believe it didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score 5):

Note that you don't necessarily have to convert text (or curves) to mesh to extrude and bevel. Those operations can be done on the geometry of the text itself.

Or you can even create a different profile to customize the edges.

[image]

**Read also:**

**[How to make a bevel on text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text)**

**[Round beveled text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text)**

Comment: Thank you. I know that and I usually work non-destructively. It is just that I am editing other person's work and everything is converted to mesh. Thanks again