# Inner bevel on letters?

Tags: modeling, bevel, text-object

I need to engrave for a project a text into a cube shape, but the big thing is that I need an inner bevel in the text, not bevel on outer edges, but a bevel into it that follows the middle of the letter.

I tried many things, impossible to obtain something like this, even with other software.

[image]

Here is what I want, I did this with Photoshop with few clicks, it makes me crazy not to be able to have this easily on Blender.

Comment: This is harder than it seems, and hopefully will come to Blender soon: [Progress on a new Bevel Geometry Node](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16dpUQ57Xv8)

Comment: Have you gone through existing answers? This gets asked quite a lot https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text