# How to I make sharp stylized inset/outset grooves like this logo

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices, edges

Here is the image. I know this is fairly simple to do, possibly just using a certain modifier. Wanted to see if anyone had any insight?
[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure that there's any automatic tool, I would draw all the lines I see then pull the middle edges

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have already been asked in various forms over time and already has a multiple answers, but you never acknowledged any of the existing posts. We are not sure if you aware of them but none of the described techniques fulfil your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: Thank you both for these answers they help immensely. @moonboots what would be the ideal way of drawing. Because I thought of doing it this way to, but I wasn't sure the most efficient way of drawing the lines.

Comment: It would first give that: https://zupimages.net/up/23/30/rpbr.jpg ... then pull the middle edges like that: https://zupimages.net/up/23/30/9e2p.jpg