# How to modify Time New Roman Letter Model 3D?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, text-object

I have a little problem.
You see I'm on training and boss ordered me to create 3D letter with serifs so I chose Times new Roman.
Okay but straight to the point, I need to make that letter look like those on pictures below.
Those letters are about to be printed in 3D and become molded or something like that idk.

[image]
[image]

Thanks, Gabe.

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: your question is not clear, you need to create a Time New Roman letter, what difficulty do you meet exactly?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss/64981#64981 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text/58498#58498

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos ! It helped me!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead.

Comment: How to upvote?.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i can't upvote till i have 15 reputation :(