# How to model text with ridges (car badge)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, topology

So I've been learning some blender the past few months but up until now I have never really used edit mode or made some hardsurface modelling.

I am trying to replicate this

[image]

First I used solidworks to set the correct dimension and make the contour, however I cannot do the bevelled top on solidworks because they are not that regular (at least i do not know how to do it). Simply adding a bevel does not work since the inside and outside bevels are not that regular... so I threw it into blender to try this out.

However hardsurface modelling is not as easy as i tought ... After importing my stl into blender I have this topology

[image]

I have cleanned it out using decimate geometry and limited disolve to end up with this

[image]

All of them except the 0 looks ok, but when i try to apply a bevel it goes haywire...

[image]

Dunno whythat happens... does anyone know an easier way to achieve what I want ? Basically there is an offset centerline on each of the characters (it is not centered it tends to be closer to the inside part of each letter) and the outside and inside bevels must coincide with it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss/64981#64981

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The geometry is too tight and the bevel overlaps.
Making the ridge manually might be easier.

1. Add a line where you need the ridge to be
2. Move it up
3. Done.

[image]

---

Start by adding inner edges in your mesh *Vertex > New Face (F)*.
Use triangles if needed.

[image]

Then select the inner edges and subdivide.
More complex cases may need manual correction.

[image]

Comment: OMG that seems so much easier, thank you so much !! Complete newbie here how do I go about creating that line, Ive been using knife cut to trace my lines, how canI do a smooth one that also connects to the vertices around it ?

Comment: Hey :). I added more info into the answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! I hope one day I am good enought to return the help !

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Good luck with your project.