# How can i achieve this 'bevel' shape effect?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, bevel

My first post here. i'm quite confused on how could i get a similar bevel style from this i did in photoshop but in blender. I know the basics on how to use an SVG file to bring a 3D extrusion, but i couldn't figure a way to  achieve this effectively.

[image]

Let's suppose i'm starting from this point here:

[image]

Comment: you need to create a central edge and move it up on the Z axis. How you'll do depends on your current topology

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216313/how-to-model-text-with-ridges-car-badge/216319#216319