# How to I create text with a rounded face?

Tags: bevel, extrude, text-object

After spending the best part of 2 days on this I'm still totally baffled. I'm trying to create a badge to be 3D printed and I'm having trouble getting the text to look right. The effect I'm going for is for the face of the text to be beveled, but not just on the corners, it needs to be pretty much a complete curve over the face of the font. Attached is a photo of the badge I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

I've tried doing this a number of ways but it hasn't given me the desired result.

- Converting the font to a mesh then using the bevel tool appeared to give me a lot of artifacts
- Trying the extrude and bevel settings in the text palette just gave me a round edge

Once I manage to get the font looking right, how would I then go about getting the underline that I plan making with an elongated cube to have the same bevel? I was able to get satisfactory results using the bevel tool, but how can I make it a perfect match?

My blend file is available here: https://formandmotion.com/5_0_Badge_18.blend

Edit: Here are the steps I took to resolve this thanks to the link in the comments below.

- Add Text object
- Convert to Curve
- Set to 3D in tool properties
- Convert to Mesh
- Mesh -> Cleanup -> Decimate Geometry to reduce the number of vertices
- Create new edge between these vertices
- Create new faces between edges
- Select new edges
- Edge -> Subdivide (twice) to split it in 3 as I wanted a rounded top
- Switch on proportional editing (smooth)
- (G)rab -> Z(key) -> 2 (to move it upwards 2mm)
- Cleanup vertices that look out of place

Comment: did you try to lower text resolution from 12 to for example 5/6 and using beautify faces? However it would still need some manual tweaking to prepare it for bevel but it sure can be done with bevel

Comment: After you convert the text to mesh, try using a Decimate Modifier set to "planar". It will leave a couple of (necessary) un-deletable edges, but this may or may not pose a problem for you. Extrude your text, add a bevel modifier set to .05 or so, with 3 or so segments. Shade smooth. If it works, it's fast. If it doesn't, well, then it doesn't. You'll have to look at other options.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text

Comment: Related: [How to model text with ridges (car badge)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216319/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal, this is exactly what I needed and I managed to get it working following this. It turned out to be a little messy with having to clean up some vertices, but from what I have seen this is to be expected.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a text,

convert it to curve,

remove the "double vertices" so that you got one single line per letter (i did it just for the c, because i was lazy) like you see in C:

[image]

uncheck cyclic in your curve object

add a circle as curve

give this circle as bevel object of your text curve

[image]

result:

[image]

you might to adjust the circle size and character spacings