# How to create a 'chiseled' bevel like in Photoshop

Tags: bevel, extrude, text-object

I'm trying to add a bevel to some text, to give a similar look to the below 'B' that I made in Photoshop using the `chiseled` option.

But I can't find anything similar in Blender? I've attached how my text is looking in Blender but all I've really changed is the `depth` and `extrude` settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss